# How to get solve to produce an answer if there are irrelevant equations?

Tags: equation-solving

Suppose I have a set of relations which I'd like to store as one variable.

```
setOfRelations = {x - y == 0, z - w == 0}
```

If I wish to obtain `w` in terms of the other variables in the system, I would have thought to do

```
Solve[setOfRelations, w]
```

with the expectation of `{{w->z}}`.  Instead the output is `{}`.  Obviously the irrelevant equations are messing up `Solve`.

What is the correct way to obtain *some result* given a set of relations, a subset of which may be coupled, and a subset of which may be irrelevant?

Comment: Are the equations going to be linear or general polynomial relationships in the variables? Or possibly more complicated than polynomials?

Comment: Maybe: `Solve[setOfRelations, w, MaxExtraConditions -> All]`

Comment: `Solve[setOfRelations, w, {x}]` or `Solve[setOfRelations, w, {y}]`

Comment: @Hugh The equations are always linear, and homogenous (equal to zero on right hand side).

Answer (score 2):

A direct approach is to delete relations without the required variables and then solve:

```
setOfRels[a_] := Select[setOfRelations, ! FreeQ[#, a] &]
Solve[setOfRels[w], w]
```

Answer (score 2):

When in doubt, try `Reduce`

```
setOfRelations = {x - y == 0, z - w == 0}

Reduce[setOfRelations, w] // ToRules
(*{x -> y, w -> z}*)
```

But this generally gives you more than you ask for.